# Ubuntu 12.04 unmet dependency error

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

I am getting the following unmet dependency issue with Ubuntu 12.04
this happened after the /boot got filled up and had to remove some of the 
old kernel packages manually.

There are no external repositories or external installations as this server
is just used for basic web hosting.

I have tried various commands below from searching on forums but none of
them work, currently I am unable to install any updates or remove any packages.

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get clean 
sudo apt-get update
```

Error message I am getting below is:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 3.2.0.77.91); however:
  Version of linux-image-generic on system is 3.2.0.79.93.
 linux-generic depends on linux-headers-generic (= 3.2.0.77.91); however:
  Version of linux-headers-generic on system is 3.2.0.79.93.
dpkg: error processing linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
```

Appreciate any help or advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check, which version you are actually running with `uname -a`.

If it is NOT 3.2.0.79.93 you should be able to remove the problematic packages with:

```
dpkg --force-depends --purge linux*3.2.0.79.93*
apt-get install -f
```

Comment: Hi Esa, unfortunately the current version is 3.2.0.79.93

Answer (score 0):

So I re-installed the linux-image-generic package, which apparently fixed the
problem, I don't think it got properly installed because of the lack of disk space
on the /boot drive.

```
sudo dpkg -r linux-generic linux-image-generic
sudo apt-get install linux-generic linux-image-generic
```